# If expected number of renewals function $U(t)$ determines a measure, what's $\int_A g(x) U(dx)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

First a bit of context.

I've seen the following convolution of measure in Resnick's Adventures in Stochastic Processes $$\int^t_0 z(t-u) U(du)$$ in which there's an abuse of notation, since $U(t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}F^{n*}(t)$, where $F^{n*}$ is the n-fold convolution of the distribution $F$. It's similar to the same abuse of notation as in $\int g(u) F(du)$.

I'm assuming $U$, i.e. $U(t)=U(-\infty,t)$ as we do for $F$ in the previous case.

$U(t)$ is supposed to be the renewal function of a process, and  $U(t)$ may not determine a distribution, but it definitely determines a measure, since $U(t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} F^{n*}(t)$, where $F^{n*}$ is the n-fold convolution of the distribution function $F$... and we have that a countable sum of measures is a measure.
In some renewal processes we have $U(t)=c+polynomial(t)$ for $x>0$. How do we do $\int g(x) U(dx)$ in this case?

If $U(A)=\int_A u(x) dx$, then by a theorem of measure theory we know that $\int_A g(x) U(dx)=\int_A g(x) u(x) dx$, where $dx$ is the lebesgue measure, and the integral is the lebesgue one.

What happens when $U((-\infty,t))=\begin{cases} 
     c+\int_{(0,t)} u(x) dx & t>0 \\
      0 & t=0
   \end{cases} $,

where $c$ is a constant?

I think we would have something as $\int_A g(x) U(dx)=c+\int_A g(x) u(x) dx$... but I'm not sure.

Also are there results for more general forms of $U$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The expression $U(A) = c + \int_{A} u(x) \, dx$ doesn't define a measure in general since $U(\phi) = c$.

Comment: @fourierwho you were right. I edited (again) the question. This time, I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, henceforth I will treat $U$ as a measure.  I claim 
$$U(dt) = c \delta_{0} + u(t) 1_{[0,\infty)} dt$$
on $\mathbb{R}$.  (Here $dt$ denotes Lebesgue measure.)  To verify this, it suffices to prove that $U$ agrees with the RHS when applied to any interval of the form $(- \infty, t)$ (with $t \in \mathbb{R}$).  As given in your definition of $U$,
\begin{align*}
U((-\infty,t)) &= \left\{ \begin{array}{r l}
c + \int_{0}^{t} u(x) \, dx & t \geq 0\\
0, & t < 0 
\end{array} \right. \\
&= c \delta_{0}((-\infty,t)) + \int_{(-\infty,t)} u(x) 1_{[0,\infty)}(x) \, dx.
\end{align*}
This proves the claim.

Now we know that if $g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is integrable with respect to $U$ (e.g. continuous) and $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a Borel set, then
$$\int_{A} g(s) \, U(ds) = c g(0) + \int_{A} g(x) u(x) \, dx.$$

As for your question regarding more general $U$, you might consider reading about bounded variation functions on $\mathbb{R}$, something called a Lebesgue decomposition, and Lebesgue-Stieltjies integrals.  Royden-Fitzpatrick *Real Analysis* could be a place to start.

Comment: fourierwho, thanks for the answer. The problem is that $U(t)$ is supposed to be the renewal function of a process, and we may have $U(t)$ not as a distribution, but it's definitely a measure, since $U(t)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} F^{n*}$, where $F^{n*}$ is the n-fold convolution of the distribution function $F$... and we have that $F^{0*}=1_{[0,\infty)}$

Comment: If you convolve functions, you get a function back.  Are you sure you're not missing something?

Comment: fourierwho, sorry for not realizing something... I doing an abuse of notation which is common in the book I'm reading. I've added some details to the PS in the question. I'm really appreciating your kindness for not giving up on this. thanks ;)

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Many thanks! I get it now. By the way, I've been searching the amazon review, and come up with several: Royden-Fitzpatrick, Folland, Richard F. Bass, and Stein-Shakarchi. What's your opinion?

Comment: By the way, I think there's a small typo when you rewrite $U((-\infty, t)$. The interval in the integral must be $[0,t)$

Comment: You're right; I added the characteristic function to be consistent throughout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69815/discussion-between-fourierwho-and-an-old-man-in-the-sea).